# Why isn't overflow: hidden working?

Tags: html, css, overflow

See http://www.collegeanswerz.com/colleges.

I just added this styling to the bottom of the page that says "Ranks according to US News." (before it wasn't styled):

```
.usnews {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.1);
}
```

This has led to a vertical scroll bar.  I don't want the scroll bar.  I googled around, and found `overflow: hidden;`.  I tried it, and it didn't work.  Then I read that for it to work, the element has to have a height.  So I gave a `height: 100%;`, but the scroll bar is still there.  How do I get rid of the scroll bar?  Here's my code:

```
@import "bootstrap";

#colleges_css {
width: 900px;
h3 {
    font-size: 17px;
}

.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.usnews {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    top: 75px;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.1);
}

.name_column { width: 25px; }
.rank_column { width: 55px; }
.location_column { width: 60px; }
.setting_column { width: 90px; }
.size_column { width: 55px; }
.cost_column { width: 75px; }
.math_column { width: 70px; }

table#national_universities_table thead tr .tablesorter-header {
    background-image: url("sort_both.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table#national_universities_table thead tr .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url("sort_asc.png");
}

table#national_universities_table thead tr .tablesorter-headerDesc {
    background-image: url("sort_desc.png");
}

table#liberal_arts_colleges_table thead tr .tablesorter-header {
    background-image: url("sort_both.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

table#liberal_arts_colleges_table thead tr .tablesorter-headerAsc {
    background-image: url("sort_asc.png");
}

table#liberal_arts_colleges_table thead tr .tablesorter-headerDesc {
    background-image: url("sort_desc.png");
}

.letters {
    font-size: 8px;
    .nav-pills > .active > a {
        background-color: rgba(0, 136, 204, 0.80);
    }
}

.list {
    -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count: 4;

    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-gap: 40px;
    ul {
        list-style-type: square;
    }
    li {
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .top_li {
        margin-top: -12px;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.letter-list {
    ul {
        list-style-type: square;
    }
    li {
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `.tab-content {overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: That got the vertical scroll away, but now the element isn't shown.

Comment: Then use `overflow: visible;`

Comment: That works.  Now I just have to give it a margin-bottom, but it's not working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use `overflow: visible` on `.tab-content`.

**Option 2:**

Use `overflow: hidden`, but this will initially cut of your `usnews` paragraph.  To fix that, remove `position: relative` and `top: 75px` and add `margin-top: 75px` and `display: inline-block` from `#colleges_css .usnews`

Comment: For option 2, margins aren't being applied to `.usnews`, and the bottom padding gets cut off.

Comment: Sorry, change `inline` to `inline-block` too.

Comment: Could you explain some of this to me?  Where are you supposed to apply overflow?  Why did relative positioning mess this up?  What's the deal with inline-block?

Comment: Well `overflow: hidden` is a common technique used for 'containing' floated elements on a page (like a clear).  But I didn't see that as necessary here, so I suggested `overflow: visible` which is the default value for that property. Relatively positioning something is normally used as a baseline to make a child absolutely positioned.  Margin is better used here and won't cause overlapping.  Display inline-block means it is placed as an inline element but behaves like a block level element (can have margins, padding etc)